# Unable to color headers in Excel file output

Tags: python-3.x

Need to put color on my excel file out but got stuck on this. [image]

Desired output is to put the color on header row but it seems that it's not implementing from columns A to CD (only from columns CE up to rest of columns) Below is my code:

```
#imported needed modules
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    
    #read data from csv
    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jdayao\Desktop\RMC_liquidation\RMC Liquidation Report 03.16.2023.csv', dtype={'Face Value':'float64', '# Accts':'int64'})
    
    #read data separate data from csv
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jdayao\Desktop\RMC_liquidation\RMC_IN\RMC_raw_latest.csv')
    
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    #converts 'Payment Date' column to datetime format
    df['Payment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Payment Date'])  
    
    #creates new column 'Month' that extracts the month using dt.to_period('M')
    df['Month'] = df['Payment Date'].dt.to_period('M')  
    
    #convert period to string
    df['Month'] = df['Payment Date'].dt.to_period('M').astype(str)  
    
    #add 1 year, always set the day = 1 to capture all transact for that month
    df_pending = (now + relativedelta(years=1)).replace(day = 1)  
                                                            
    # group and flag as future months 
    df.loc[(df['Payment Date'] >= df_pending),'Month'] = f"{df_pending.strftime('%B %Y')} - All Futures"   
    
    # will group months as a list
    unique_months = list(df.Month.unique())  
    unique_pids = list(df.pid.unique())
                                           
    # added :02 here for month reformatting             
    data[f'{now.year}-{now.month:02}'] = 0        
    data[f'{now.year}-{now.month:02} - PDC'] = 0
    
    #used for loop and some filtering conditions here
    for item in unique_pids:
        data.loc[(data['PID'] == item) ,f'{now.year}-{now.month:02}'] = df[(df['pid'] == item) & (df['Month'] == f'{now.year}-{now.month:02}') & (df['status'] == 'posted')]['payment_amount'].sum()
       
    #used for loop and some filtering conditions here
    for item in unique_pids:
        data.loc[(data['PID'] == item) ,f'{now.year}-{now.month:02} - PDC'] = df[(df['pid'] == item) & (df['Month'] == f'{now.year}-{now.month:02}') & (df['status'].isin(['pending','processed']))]['payment_amount'].sum()
    
    #to remove the current month
    unique_months.remove(f'{now.year}-{now.month:02}')    
    
    # to get the date of the first day of next month then set as day 1
    next_month = (now + relativedelta(months=1)).replace(day=1)  
    
    col_names_list = []
    for item in list(data.columns):
        #print(item)
        if item not in ['Client', 'Portfolio', 'PID', 'Fee %', 'Face Value', '# Accts', 'Date Placed'] and 'pdc' not in item.lower() and  'future' not in item.lower():
            col_names_list.append(item)
    
    i=0
    for future_date in unique_months:
        future_month = future_date
        # removed future_payments_ and retain future_month value align header name with the orig report file 
        column_name = f"{future_month}"  
        # initialized the new columns with a default value of 0.0 
        data[column_name] = 0.0  
        
        column_name_alt = f"All $ Pending"  # removed future_payments_ and retain future_month value align header name with the orig report file  # change here
        # initialized the new columns with a default value of 0.0 
        data[column_name_alt] = 0.0 
        for pid in unique_pids:
            # for future payments
            future_payments = df[(df['status'].isin(['pending','processed'])) & (df['Month'] == future_month) & (df['pid'] == pid)]['payment_amount'].sum()
            future_payments_alt = df[(df['status'].isin(['pending','processed'])) & (df['pid'] == pid)]['payment_amount'].sum()
            
            data.loc[(data['PID'] == pid), column_name] = future_payments
            data.loc[(data['PID'] == pid), column_name_alt] = future_payments_alt
        i+=1
    
    # to prevent future type error: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html
    data['All $ Posted'] = data[col_names_list].sum(axis=1,numeric_only=True) 
    data['All Collections'] = data['All $ Posted'] + data['All $ Pending']
    
    # computation to get 'Posted $ Liq %'
    data['Posted $ Liq %'] = data['All $ Posted'] / data['Face Value']  
    
    # stored totals here for liq % computations
    all_posted_total = data['All $ Posted'].sum()
    all_collections_total = data['All Collections'].sum()
    face_value_total = data['Face Value'].sum()
    
    # computation to get the 'All collections Liq $'
    data['All Collections Liq %'] = data['All Collections'] / data['Face Value'] 
    
    # this will get the summation of all columns/headers
    data.loc['total'] = data.sum() 
    
     # -1 indicates that it will cover until last row [0, 1, 2, ... , -2, -1]
    data.loc[data.index[-1], 'Client'] = ''       
    data.loc[data.index[-1], 'Portfolio'] = ''
    data.loc[data.index[-1], 'PID'] = ''
    data.loc[data.index[-1], 'Fee %'] = 'TOTALS'
    data.loc[data.index[-1], 'Date Placed'] = '-'
    
    
    # re-arrange these lines or create logic to 
    data.loc[data.index[-1], 'Posted $ Liq %'] = all_posted_total / face_value_total   #result on this sums up the total in columns as well
    
    data.loc[data.index[-1], 'All Collections Liq %'] = all_collections_total / face_value_total #result on this sums up the total in columns as well
    
    # create the filename with the current date
    filename = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('RMC-Liquidation-Report-%m.%d.%Y.xlsx')
    
    # to create a Pandas ExcelWriter using XlsxWriter as the engine
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'C:/Users/jdayao/Desktop/RMC_liquidation/RMC_OUT/{filename}', engine='xlsxwriter') 
    
    # to write the DataFrame to a worksheet named 'RMC Liq.'
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='RMC Liq.', index=False) 
    
    ########################################################################################################################
    
    # prep for money currency format
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['RMC Liq.']
    
    # to change to currency format
    money_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '[$$-409]#,##0.00'}) 
    
    # keep value 20 , E:E location of column  <start : end>
    worksheet.set_column('E:E', 20, money_fmt)   
    
    # logic for dates columns/headers
    end_money_fmt = len(list(data.columns)) - 3  
    
    # worksheet.set_column(<start>,<end>, <cell width>, <format>)
    worksheet.set_column(7,end_money_fmt, 20, money_fmt)   
    
    # Equations to define start/end for percentage format
    start_percentage_fmt = end_money_fmt + 1
    end_percentage_fmt = start_percentage_fmt + 2
    
    # to change to percentage format
    percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})  
    worksheet.set_column(start_percentage_fmt, end_percentage_fmt, 20, percent_format)
    
    # to put color on header
    header_color_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#4883C2'})  
    worksheet.set_row(0, 20, header_color_format)  # this still do not put colors on headers but following the rows(this also change the format of the rows)
    
    # to freeze columns from A to G
    worksheet.freeze_panes(0, 7)  
    
    #save and close the file
    writer.close()
```

Comment: The reason why this happens and how to work around it is explained in the XlsxWriter "Working with Pandas" documentation on [Formatting of the Dataframe headers](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers).